# How can i get all SKMap location objects so I can filter trough them?

Tags: ios, skmaps

I use `SKMap` in a offline navigation iOS application and:

I'm trying to search from a `UITextField` a street/city/district within a preinstalled map and I want to get all objects that matches my search.
How can I get all map location objects so I can filter trough them?
From the sample didn't quite managed to do so.(I get only cities)

Is there other alternative or I must loop trough every city and get streets (Seems ugly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [SKNearbySearchSettings](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/Classes/SKNearbySearchSettings.html) class and to set

```
searchObject.searchType = SKAll;
```

A more detailed example of using this class (should return all streets and POIs containing the "pizza" keyword):

```
SKNearbySearchSettings *searchObject = [SKNearbySearchSettings nearbySearchSettings];

searchObject.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.5233, 13.4127); 
searchObject.radius = 40000;        
searchObject.searchMode = SKSearchHybrid;
searchObject.searchResultSortType  = SKMatchSort;    
searchObject.searchType = SKAll;
searchObject.searchTerm = "pizza";

[[SKSearchService sharedInstance]startNearbySearchWithSettings:searchObject];
```

Comment: Works great but I want to get from a whole continent and radius max is 65 km and I want to get "Street name, District name". Is there any possibility of doing that? Thank you very much!

Comment: Played a little bit with sdk and found out that SKSearchResult has parents. It's great. Thank you!